# I am making voice assistant in pycharm. It was working fine week ago but now it is showing assertion erorr from __init__.py file

Tags: python, assert, init, voice-recognition

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if 0 <= hour < 12:
        speak("Good Morning")
    elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
        speak("Good Afternoon")
    else:
        speak("Good Evening")
    speak("I am Edith. How can I help you sir?")


def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 0.4
        audio = r.listen(source)
        r.energy_threshold = 270

    try:
        print("Recognizing")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-us')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Say that again please...")
        return "none"
    return query


if __name__ == "__main__":
    wishMe()
    while True:
        query = takeCommand().lower()
        if 'wikipedia' in query:
            speak('Searching on wikipedia...')
            query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
            results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=3)
            speak("According to wikipedia")
            print(results)
            speak(results)
        elif 'open youtube' in query:
            webbrowser.open("youtube.com")
```

```
ERROR:-
C:\Users\hp1\PycharmProjects\pythonvoiceassistant\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/hp1/PycharmProjects/pythonvoiceassistant/main.py
Listening...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp1\PycharmProjects\pythonvoiceassistant\main.py", line 50, in <module>
    query = takeCommand().lower()
  File "C:\Users\hp1\PycharmProjects\pythonvoiceassistant\main.py", line 34, in takeCommand
    audio = r.listen(source)
  File "C:\Users\hp1\PycharmProjects\pythonvoiceassistant\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 595, in listen
    assert self.pause_threshold >= self.non_speaking_duration >= 0
AssertionError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It is showing assertionerror. I haven't used the keyword assert still it is showing error. It is showing error from **init**.py file. It was working fine and recognizing my speech but few days ago it suddenly starts showing this error. I have tried creating completely new project in pycharm and even installed all modules again but it is still showing the error. It works fine until code of voice recognition starts. It wishes me "Good Morning, I am Edith. How can I help you sir?" after greeting, it shows this error. Please help me I have been trying and searching for some solution online for 2 weeks and now I finally post my query on stackoverflow for some answers.

Comment: please format the error listing the same as code ... did it for you

Comment: Did you speak into the microphone, what did you say, and how long did you speak for?

Comment: maybe you should `listen()` inside `try/except` to catch problem.

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in question's title

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
File "C:\Users\hp1\PycharmProjects\pythonvoiceassistant\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 595, in listen
assert self.pause_threshold >= self.non_speaking_duration >= 0
```

This is saying that the assert is in the speech_recognition package, in other words, not in your code.
The assert is saying that the pause_threshold should be greater or equal to the non_speaking_duration, and both values cannot be negative.

In your code you are setting the pause_threshold to 0.4, but not setting a non_speaking_duration, so my guess would be that the default non_speaking_duration is greater than 0.4 which is triggering the assert.

One way to check would be to put `print(r.non_speaking_duration)` after the `print("Listening...")` line.

Update: when I do this I get a value of 0.5 for the non_speaking_duration, so a simple fix is to set `r.pause_threshold = 0.5`

Comment: I changed the value of pause threshold. Now it is not showing error but now on terminal it greets then it is written Listening... , then I speak it is giving no response like it is stuck on Listening..

Comment: Yeah, I also have the same issue on my mac. Are you on a mac too?

Comment: If so, there is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62756231/python-speech-recognition-is-stuck-mac. Using the regular mac terminal rather than the pycharm integrated one works for me.